How do add EF core migrations with WindowsAppSDK project?
How do you set up EF Core migrations for a desktop application using WindowsAppSDK?
Problems

Running dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate fails because building a self contained WindowsAppSDK requires you to specify platform on build
Running dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --no-build after building with msbuild -p:Platform:x64 fails because the migrations command looks for the build result in bin/Debug instead of bin/x64/Debug
I also tried to create a separate startup project for migrations only but now I have no way to run the migrations programmatically since it would require reference to the new start up project which breaks the build.

Using EF Core 6
